# How to allow application vendor (only) to detect tampering of log files?

Tags: c#, security, authentication, hash, password-protection

I'm trying to figure out the best way to sign data (log-data, etcetera) written to file by a C# desktop application. Somehow the application, and the application only, needs a private key (secret) to encrypt the checksum/hash of the data.

The reason: Only the vendor should be able to tell if data produced by the application has been tampered. Only the integrity of the data is importent. Confidentiality is not a problem (encryption not needed).

The vendor has no control of the on-site installation process (read: can't enter secret manually during the installation process).

The customers doesn't nessecarily have a Internet connection or other means to retrieve the secret from a secure communication line.

Users (customers) may or may not have admininstrator-privileges on the computer where the application is executing.

The vendor will NOT hardcode (and obfuscate) the secret inside the application (or its installer).

Installing a certificate containing a private key along with the application seems to be a dumb idea, but maybe its not?

Is it possible to sign the application with a certificate and extract the secret/private key from the certificate somehow? (implementing a mechanism to create a private key is NOT a good idea, though. The secret must be associated with the key only according to good security principles).

Does anyone have any experience with the best way to solve this challange?

Comment: Unfortunately some questions can be answered only with "not possible" answer. If you want to sign the data, you need to keep the private key on the client side. And there it's reachable to the user.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Eugene. I thought so too, but I hoped someone had come up with a solution to this scenario. Like having all windows machines install a private machine key only the OS (and not even administrators) know of or something - but even then the private key is still available for a skilled hacker. Yeah, not possible. I might end up obfuscating a private key then even if its considered bad practice.

Comment: well, potentially you can use a USB cryptotoken - the private key can't be extracted from it (some tokens can be attacked to reveal the key bit by bit, but that's another story).